# Quick manipulation of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following example data frame:

```
> a = data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(10, 11, 12), c=c(1, 1, 0))
> a
  a  b c
1 1 10 1
2 2 11 1
3 3 12 0
```

I want to do an operation to every row where if `a$c == 1`, `a$a = a$b`, otherwise, `a$a` keeps its value. The final data frame a should look like this:

```
> a
  a  b c
1 10 10 1
2 11 11 1
3  3 12 0
```

What is the fastest way to do this? Of course in my problem I have hundreds of thousands of rows, so looping over the entire data frame and doing one by one is extremely slow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy as 1-2-3:

```
df = data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(10, 11, 12), c=c(1, 1, 0))
df$a[df$c == 1] <- df$b[df$c == 1]
df
##    a  b c
## 1 10 10 1
## 2 11 11 1
## 3  3 12 0
```

It reads: *substitute all the elements in `a` corresponding to `c==1` with all the elements in `b` corresponding to `c==1`*.

A benchmark:

```
df <- data.frame(a=runif(100000), b=runif(100000), c=sample(c(1,0), 100000, replace=TRUE))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(df$a[df$c == 1] <- df$b[df$c == 1], df$a <- with(df, ifelse(c == 1, b, a)))
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                    expr      min       lq    median       uq       max neval
##      df$a[df$c == 1] <- df$b[df$c == 1] 13.85375 15.13073  16.61701  74.5387  88.47949   100
##  df$a <- with(df, ifelse(c == 1, b, a)) 44.23750 78.85029 103.01894 105.1750 118.09492   100
```

Comment: Maybe the fastest answer in the history of Stackoverflow? Thank you very much! A pity I still need 10 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: I've seen faster ones. Anyway, [R intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#Index-vectors) is your friend. Good luck with your further R studies!

Answer (score 3):

```
a$a <- with(a, ifelse(c == 1, b, a))
```